# SSIS - How to get the UserName system variable in a custom component in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Is there a way to get the Username of the user that started the package inside of a custom component?  I know how in a script component and script task, but I am look how to in a user created custom SSIS component?

Thanks!

Comment: _Should_ be about the same but you might have to go through the VariableDispenser methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.unlock?view=sqlserver-2019  It's been a decade since I spent any time with custom components. And since you specified component, you'll likely need to access this in the PreExecute phase. Otherwise, you'll need to show some sample code for me to get my brain back into the game. The samples were on CodePlex and I don't know how well they moved over to github

Comment: @billinkc Yes, you are correct in needing to use the VariableDispenser methods.  I posted this question one google search too soon!  I just found the answer right after I posted this question.  Thanks for you answer and help!

Comment: Get yourself some points and post it as an answer so in a decade from now, the next person finds a good answer at their fingertips

Comment: I agree, please take the time to post an explanation of what you did. Then this won't be one of those google searches where you find exactly the right question with no answer

Comment: Thanks guys!  I posted the answer and code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after I posted the question.  Hope this helps anyone else looking to get system variables inside a custom component.  Below is the code I used to get the UserName system variable inside a custom component.

```
IDTSVariables100 variables = null;
this.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("System::UserName");
this.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out variables);

String userName = variables["System::UserName"].Value.ToString();
variables.Unlock();
```